# PowerShell/PowerCli to pass Correct parameter from Out-GridView for Snapshot removal

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I am a PowerShell/PowerCLI newbie, now I'm learning it for work. I've created a simple few lines code to list all snapshots and use the out-gridview to list it in another popup window, selecting one or multiple snapshots and click on "Ok" will let me delete the selected snapshot and it worked without issue.

```
#List snapshot
$snapshot = Get-VM | Get-Snapshot | Out-GridView -Title "Snapshot Viewer" -OutputMode Multiple

#remove selected VM's snapshot
$snapshot | foreach { Remove-Snapshot $_ }
```

Because default `Get-Snapshot` only displays Snapshot Name, Description, and PowerState, I added a counter, VM Name, Snapshot Size in GB and age of the snapshot.

```
$counter = 1

#List snapshot with more information
$snapshot = Get-VM | Get-Snapshot | 
            Select-Object @{Name="ID";Expression={$global:counter;$global:counter++}}, 
                VM, Name, @{Name="SizeGB";Expression={[math]::Round($_.sizeGB,2)}},
                @{Name="Days";Expression={(New-TimeSpan -End (Get-Date) -Start $_.Created).Days}} |
            Out-GridView -Title "Snapshot Viewer" -OutputMode Multiple

#remove selected VM's snapshot
$snapshot | foreach { Remove-Snapshot $_ }
```

And now the `$_` seems to return the wrong parameter for `Remove-Snapshot` and get an error:

```
Remove-Snapshot : Cannot bind parameter 'Snapshot'. Cannot convert the
"@{ID=4; VM=Win7-Golden; Name=SS20170227 v3.1; SizeGB=0.00; Days=64}"
value of type "Selected.VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.VM.SnapshotImpl"
to type "VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Types.V1.VM.Snapshot".
At D:\powershell\snapshot_with_index.ps1:10 char:39
+ $snapshot | foreach { Remove-Snapshot $_ }
+                                       ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Snapshot], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.RemoveSnapshot
```

Appreciate if anyone can give me guidance on how to solve this error, to pass the correct parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select-Object` changes the object type to `PSCustomObject`, but [`Remove-Snapshot`](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/Remove-Snapshot.html) seems to expect a snapshot object.

I don't have access to a vSphere system, but if you want to allow filtering by a gridview with "enhanced information" you probably need to store the snapshots in an array first, and then get the selected snapshots from that array for deletion.

Something like this might work:

```
$snapshots = @(Get-VM | Get-Snapshot)

0..($snapshots.Count - 1) | ForEach-Object {
    $i = $_
    $snapshots[$i] | Select-Object @{n='ID';e={$i}}, ...
} | Out-GridView -Title "Snapshot Viewer" -OutputMode Multiple | ForEach-Object {
    Remove-Snapshot $snapshots[$_.ID]
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks for the guidance and sorry for late reply!